# Why is the prayer on leaving the Sukkah unique?

Tags: sukkot

Many have a custom to recite a short prayer upon leaving the sukkah - the yehi ratzon found in many machzorim/soddurim. Why don’t other mitzvot have a similar phenomenon? Why don’t we find similar prayers by shofar or matzah etc?

Comment: I imagine it‘s similar to a guest taking leave of his host before leaving - we’ve been dwelling in Hashem’s house all week and now wish to return to our own homes.

Comment: The prayer (the version I'm familiar with) is asking that we merit something for doing the _mitzva_. We have a similar prayers after _arava_, before _lulav_, and doubtless before or after many other _mitzvos_.

Comment: I vaguely recall some opinion stating that one **must** leave the succah and sit in his home on Shmini Atzeret. I have to see if I can find this. This idea would seem to warrant a prayer to demonstrate this act. The other mitzvoth that you mentioned don't have an "ending" time.